# Using a .env in a html and js file

Tags: javascript, html, environment-variables

How would I use an .env file in my html file and javascript file?

In my .env file I have:

```
GOOGLE_API_TOKEN=token
```

In my html file I have:

```
<iframe id="maps" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=GOOGLE_API_TOKEN&q=United+States" width="600" height="450" style="border:0" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

I'm not sure how to obtain the token from the .env file and put it into the iframe src.

Since I'm new to using .env files, I'm not sure how to access the token in my javascript file.

[Directory Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34eHv.png)

I've tried using the backtick, but that doesn't work in html.
For javascript I've tried import and require, but can't do that.

Comment: HTML and clientside javascript are not able to access .env files; you would need to inject this token into the HTML on the server or during a build process before publishing to the web.

Comment: @DanielBeck is there an alternative to using an .env file to store api tokens?